# Can Eclipse Color Theme vary by file type?

Tags: eclipse

Can Eclipse Color Theme vary by file type?

The common answer I have seen is to use different workspaces. I find this unsatisfactory. I only have one project, but it uses Python, JavaScript, CSS, XML and probably some others I'm forgetting. I don't think I should need to create a different workspace for all of them.